# Difficulty with .htaccess pretty URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess

I apologize if this has been asked numerous times, all of the reading I've done I can't seem to figure this out.

I'm building a site where the index page loads a template based on the url "index.php?p=pagename". This is working fine, however in some instances I need to pass an id as well "index.php?p=pagename&id=#". Ideally I would like it to look like... /pagename/id or /pagename/id/...

here's what my hatccess file looks like.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /manage/
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ ?p=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: Also check if your server has mod rewrite enabled

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the duplication, I guess there's never an explanation of.. if you set it up to handle two parameters, it also works with only one parameter. That's where my confusion may have been happening.

Comment: mod rewrite is enabled. As I mentioned, the first rewrite rule is working perfectly. As I'm building the site, I've come across a need to occasionally pass an id for $_GET.... and it just isn't happening. Unfortunately I have very little understanding of hatches....

Comment: *htaccess... spell check changed it to 'hatches'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /manage/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /manage/index.php?p=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /manage/index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This isn't working. do I maybe need to change how I'm writing the href for page links?

Comment: In which folder is the index.php file?

Comment: You also need to add a base tag to the head of your document so that pages can  can use css and other relative links

Comment: There is a config file that defines the base url as well as the base directory included in the index page

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding something, this still isn't working. My page links look like: '<a href=/manage/pagename>' which works with my first rewrite rule from my post, it also works without '/manage/', but doesn't work with the rule you've posted.

Comment: Now the variables have changed in url, there are 2 variables now , wait I will update my answer again in a short while.

Comment: so with your update, using the link '/manage/news' works to give me the news page, but '/manage/edit-news/5' does not.

Comment: A hypen - was missing in the regex pattern, i have fixed it.